# mkp224o vanity address

Tags: onion-routing, address

I used mkp224o to generate a v3 address in .onion, but I was wondering how do I add it? I have a server already with the tor installed mkp224o generates these 3 files "hostname", "hs_ed25519_public_key" and "hs_ed25519_secret_key" I left it like this:

- HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/v3/
- HiddenServiceVersion 3
- HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

and added the 3 files generated by mkp224o inside that folder /var/lib/tor/v3/ but it didn't work, all ports are open, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work? What does your Tor log say?

Comment: Yes, I added it, but when I enter the URL it doesn’t work NGINX is already installed I did the process without using mkp224o generating a random url of the tor itself and it worked, but it doesn’t work what do you think I did wrong?

Comment: You didn't say if there are errors in your Tor log. Also did you make sure the file permissions and owner are correct?

Comment: good friend thank you so much I read the logs and ended up getting just permissions from the folders.

Answer (score 1):

thank you very much for those who tried to help, but I have already found out by reading the logs what it was like if someone ever had the same problem the solution is the following: you should not give permissions to / var / lib / tor as root user because user of that folder is "debian-tor" everything inside it must be in the permissions of this user or an error will occur, I solved it with the following commands.

chmod 700 -R /var/lib/tor/*

chown  -R debian-tor /var/lib/tor/*

systemctl restart tor